# default value for react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to change default value for my react-select but when I but default value it won't let me change to another option.

here is my following code:

```
  const find = (value) => {
    setSearchUsers(value.some((element) => element.value === "Users"));
    setSearchTeams(value.some((element) => element.value === "Teams"));
    setSearchOrganizations(
      value.some((element) => element.value === "Organizations")
    );
  };

      <Select
        className="search-select"
        styles={customStyles}
        instanceId="long-value-select"
        closeMenuOnSelect={false}
        components={animatedComponents}
        defaultValue="Select"
        isMulti
        onChange={find}
        options={searchData}
        theme={(theme) => ({
          ...theme,
          colors: {
            ...theme.colors,
            neutral50: "#fff",
          },
        })}
      />
```

Comment: What framework/design system are you using? Check this line: `defaultValue="Select"`
Here you should use a computed value (a js object) or the string that refer to the key of one option of your set of options.

Comment: I am using nextjs